# Upload Nodejs - Express Server on Cpanel

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, api, cpanel

I've created a server using NodeJs on localhost:3000 for my angular application. When user will submit contact form, server will run the script and send an email.

Everything working fine on localhost but when I upload on Cpanel, its giving an error `Internal Server Error: 500`.
I've created Node application from Cpanel. Root file is server.js. `var http` is auto generated by Cpanel. Rest of the things, I've added.

Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const sendMail = require('./mail.js');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
var http = require('http');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());


var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    var message = 'It works!\n',
    version = 'NodeJS ' + process.versions.node + '\n',
    response = [message, version].join('\n');
    res.end(response);
});
server.listen();

app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {

    const { name, email, phone, subject, message} = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({message: req.body});

    sendMail(name, email, phone, subject, message, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Error'});
        } else {
            res.json({message: 'Email Sent!!!!!'});
        }
    });
    
})
```

mail.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mailGun = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');

const auth = {
    auth: {
        api_key: 'privatekey-381f2624-ccbf9964',
        domain: 'domain-17bb134be0f54584b0e8751d3a3ec19b.mailgun.org'
    }
};


const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(mailGun(auth));


const sendMail = (name, email, phone, subject, message, cb) => {
    const mailOptions = {
        from: email,
        to: 'webmaster@gmail.com',
        subject: subject,
        text: 'Name: ' + name + '\n Email:' + email + '\n Phone: ' + phone + '\n Message: ' + message
    };
    
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            cb(err, null);
        } else {
            cb(null, data);
        }
    });
}


module.exports = sendMail;
```

Angular EmailService where I placed this api link.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmailService {

  _url = 'https://gump.akc-uae.com/api/submit';
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  contact(clientData:any) {
  return this._http.post<any>(this._url, clientData);
  }
}
```

Its my first attempt to upload Node app on Cpanel.

Comment: Try: In `server.listen()` pass 'process.env.PORT'

Comment: the homepage is working fine. Only post function on submit contact form is not working.

Answer (score 0):

ok. you were calling the `sendMail` function after sending the response.

Your code should be:

```
app.post('/submit', async function(req, res) {

    const { name, email, phone, subject, message} = req.body;        

    try{
     await sendMail(name, email, phone, subject, message, 
     function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal Error'});
        } else {
            res.json({message: 'Email Sent!!!!!'});
        }
    });
    res.status(200).json({message: req.body});
  }catch(error){
    res.json({message: error.message});
  }
    
})
```

*Note:* make your sendMail function promise

Comment: It's still giving me 500 Server Error.

Comment: share your `sendMail` function code. lets debug

Comment: I've updated the question. One more thing. I just checked the server.js file on the cpanel. I can only redirect to ```/``` this. If I write any function like ```server.get('/test')```, Its giving me the same error.

Comment: Is your code working fine in local ?

Comment: Yes everything is fine on my local. I served angular on ```localhost:4200``` & Nodejs on ```localhost:3000```. I'm sending and receiving emails through mailgun.

Comment: There will be an option like `npm start`,  `npm install` in cPanel's. Once you transferred your project to cpanel, Select the server.js file as the start file and first click on `npm install` and then `npm start`. If you didnt do npm install the neccessary packages will not be added in your project. so what happens is it will throw Internal error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248644/discussion-between-vivek-rahul-and-muhammad-shahzaib).